# Why would the label of the vertical axis only show after the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am working on a website which needs to show something on the chart (highchart) upon clicking of a button.

The issue is: when the page is first loaded, the label on the vertical axis can not be seen, no matter how big I set the margin for the chart. However, after the button is clicked for the first time, the labels can be seen and remains so.

There was no such problem before I set "reversed", "opposite" for xAxis and "reversed" for yAxis as true.

What causes this phenomenon and how can I solve this?

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6ymuxr/83/) for detail. (There are some logic mistakes in the code which is irrelevant for my question.)

I just discovered that when I first load the JSFiddle, the vertical axis of the graph shows up with label; but when I click on "Run" additionally, the graph is refreshed with a vertical axis without label. Maybe I can simulate certain process which takes place when a JSFiddle is loaded to make sure that the vertical axis of the graph shows up with labels. But I am not sure how to do that.

Browser: Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit) (up to date)
My OS: Windows 10

Code for the generation of the chart:

```
function createColumnHorizChart(argMinY = minYAxis, argMaxY = maxYAxis) {



var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { //not to be changed lightly
      renderTo: 'contr2',
      type: 'bar',
      width: 749,
      marginTop: 5,
      marginLeft: 1,
      marginRight: 90,
      marginBottom: 55
    },
    colors: [
      '#0000ff'
    ],
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['smaller than 100', '100 - 110', '110 - 120', '120 - 130', '130 - 140', '140 - 150', 'bigger than 150'],
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      startOnTick: true,
      title: {
        text: 'Money Unit (MU)'
      },
      opposite: true,
      reversed: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      reversed: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 15,
      tickInterval: 5,
      title: {
        text: 'Frequency',
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
        return {
          x: point.plotX - 50,
          y: point.plotY - 10
        };
      },
      style: {
        fontSize: "10px",
        fontWeight: "unbold"
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return Math.round(chartData[index - 2] * 100) / 100;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      series: {
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        animation: false, //disable all the animations,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
      }
    },
    series: [{
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      data: Array(7).fill(0)
    }]
  });

  return chart;
}
```

Comment: For me, everything works fine on the newest releases of Chrome and Firefox browsers. Could you try to add more detailed information about which browser and os are you running?

Comment: So, it's only possible to reproduce on Windows platform. Could you provide us also with minified demo where the problem occurs? I'm asking because in current demo there are a lot of lines which are unnecessary. Additionally, until we find the source of the problem, you can workaround it by calling `this.reflow()` in `chart.events.load` event handler.

Comment: @daniel_s Thank you for the workaround. Is this minified demo OK: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6ymuxr/99/

Comment: @daniel_s You may also add your comment as an answer.

Comment: I think that your example should be even more minified. There are a lot of functions, HTML elements, which could be removed from there.

Comment: I think it is better now: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6ymuxr/106/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's only possible to reproduce on Windows platform. Could you provide us also with minified demo where the problem occurs? I'm asking because in current demo there are a lot of lines which are unnecessary.

Additionally, until we find the source of the problem, you can workaround it by calling this.reflow() in chart.events.load event handler.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.reflow()
    }
  }
}
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but it works fine when you remove the marginLeft property or set it to 0.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that if marginLeft is 0, the left border of the chart would be invisible. I think we might be able to increase the width of only the left border but I am not sure how to do so.